# Eclipse: Remove General preference page from preferences

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a my own preferencepage but one more preference page named General is added by default, how to remove or hide it from my preference

Comment: Is this the normal Eclipse 'General' page with things like 'Always run in background' on it, or something else?

Comment: A picture of the page would help.

Comment: Yes, thats the Page iam having problem with